# NSWindow Mac App Store like Title Bar

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

How could I make an `NSWindow`'s title bar look like that of the Mac App Store or of the app Feeder where it's height is increased and other controls are show in it.

To see what I mean just check out the website for the Mac App Store : http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/.

Is it a custom `NSWindow` or is it a completely borderless window with an `NSView` made to look like the title bar?

Comment: That's a terrible-looking window.  Please don't do that. :(

Comment: Don't worry. I have no intention to, I'm just curious. :)

Comment: Look for UIKitMac on Twitter. @Timstarockz is working on it.

Comment: @Alexsander That definitely looks promising, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow

> **Title bar and traffic light customization for NSWindow**
>
> `INAppStoreWindow` is an NSWindow subclass that was originally developed to mimic the appearance of the main window in the Mac App Store application introduced in OS X 10.6.6.
>
> The MAS application has since transitioned away from this design, but `INAppStoreWindow` is still being actively developed to provide extensive additional customization options for `NSWindow` title bars...

Answer (score 1):

For iTunes (v9.x) Apple used no toolbar, but custom aligned icons and controls in the top bar, to achieve a similar effect. (see link below)

The window looks like a "textured & unified title and toolbar" window to me. (or a slight variant of such)

To reposition the traffic light buttons follow my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass/4309332#4309332).

However, as Dave DeLong already (similarly) commented: "**The UI is terrible. Please don't even think about it.**"

Comment: I disagree with _"The UI is terrible. Please don't even think about it."_. Many apps have used this elegantly with great results. (Reeder for Mac jumps to mind.) What is so "terrible" about verticaly centering elements in relation to eachother?

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at http://orestis.gr/blog/2007/09/24/messing-with-windows/ . This uses some undocumented stuff, though, so it won't actually get approved FOR the App Store.