# I want to create a nswindow like itunes min status,but I have no idea

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iTunes-style NSWindow subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass)

I want to create nswindow like itunes min status.
like:
[image: ituens]

but when I create the nswindow it like this:
[image: nswindow i create]

I want  a panel like itunes that show at up picture.so I can put my custom view in it.
but i have no idea how to do it.I am new for mac design.

Any suggestion is welcome  or can any one remmend same useful books for me.

Comment: thank you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass

Comment: I got an other question.how can I hide the titlebar of the window?

Comment: please search for these questions on SO or open a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an NSPanel and select the metal appearance to get something similar to the iTunes window. However, iTunes is drawing the non-standard close/max/min buttons itself, so you can't easily reproduce that (nor should you want to IMHO).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass

Comment: thank you. the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass  whit Eimantas' help.