# How do you create NSWindow title bar to be transparent, but not the content of the window itself?

Tags: cocoa

I am in the process of creating a small image editor. 
What I aim, is to create a window with transparent titlebar, but not what contains inside the window.

I have check HUD Window, but it's really is a panel, not a window. And I am missing the regular close,maximize and minimize button.

Is there anyway to create such window?
Or can we modify HUD to hold regular close,max and min button?

Thanks so much in advance!
Eko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [standard borderless window](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BorderlessWindow) approach and provide a content view that draws something. Even if the content view's bounds rect is just filled with `[NSColor whiteColor]`.

**Update:** Re-reading, I see you seem to be asking for just a transparent title bare but still with the window controls. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass) for an approach at customizing a window's title bar. Careful, though - I'm not sure this would be accepted into the App Store. Best to have a backup plan in case it's not.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Nozzi. Your update is correct. But the link to that article, is not quite what I am looking for. I'll answer my own question, because I found the solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that match to what I want : [window trasparency](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/96267-window-transparency.html)
The trick is making the main window transparent, but not the content by creating a special view for this.