# How to rotate close, minimize and zoom buttons in title bar like in iTunes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, titlebar

I want to see close, minimize and zoom buttons vertically in title bar like in iTunes.

How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTunes-style NSWindow subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304186/itunes-style-nswindow-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a borderless window and draw the window frame and widgets yourself. Matt Gallagher has an example project that you can adapt to do what you want:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html

Word of warning: don't expect your users or fellow developers to love you for implementing this.